# MSE in neuralnet results and roc curve of the results

Tags: neural-network

Hi my question is a bit long please bare and read it till the end.

I am working on a project with 30 participants. We have two type of data set (first data set has 30 rows and 160 columns , and second data set has the same 30 rows and 200 columns as outputs=y and these outputs are independent), what i want to do is to use the first data set and predict the second data set outputs.As first data set was rectangular type and had high dimension i have used factor analysis and now have 19 factors that cover up to 98% of the variance. Now i want to use these 19 factors for predicting the outputs of the second data set.

I am using neuralnet and backpropogation and everything goes well and my results are really close to outputs.

My questions :

1- as my inputs are the factors ( they are between -1 and 1 ) and my outputs scale are between 4 to 10000 and integer , should i still scaled them before running neural network ?

2-I scaled the data ( both input and outputs ) and then predicted with neuralnet , then i check the MSE error it was so high like 6000 while my prediction and real output are so close to each other. But if i rescale the prediction and outputs then check The MSE its near zero. Is it unbiased to rescale and then check the MSE ?

3- I read that it is better to not scale the output from the beginning but if i just scale the inputs all my prediction are 1. Is it correct to not to scale the outputs ?

4- If i want to plot the ROC curve how can i do it. Because my results are never equal to real outputs ?

Thank you for reading my question

Answer (score 0):

[edit#1]: There is a publication on how to produce ROC curves using neural network results 
http://www.lcc.uma.es/~jja/recidiva/048.pdf

1) You can scale your values (using minmax, for example). But only scale your training data set. Save the parameters used in the scaling process (in minmax they would be the min and max values by which the data is scaled). Only then, you can scale your test data set WITH the min and max values you got from the training data set. Remember, with the test data set you are trying to mimic the process of classifying unseen data. Unseen data is scaled with your scaling parameters from the testing data set.

2) When talking about errors, do mention which data set the error was computed on. You can compute an error function (in fact, there are different error functions, one of them, the mean squared error, or MSE)  on the training data set, and one for your test data set.

4) Think about this: Let's say you train a network with the testing data set,and it only has 1 neuron in the output layer . Then, you present it with the test data set. Depending on which transfer function (activation function) you use in the output layer, you will get a value for each exemplar. Let's assume you use a sigmoid transfer function, where the max and min values are 1 and 0. That means the predictions will be limited to values between 1 and 0.

Let's also say that your target labels ("truth") only contains discrete values of 0 and 1 (indicating which class the exemplar belongs to).

```
targetLabels=[0   1   0   0   0   1   0  ];
NNprediction=[0.2 0.8 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.7 0.2];
```

How do you interpret this?
You can apply a hard-limiting function such that the NNprediction vector only contains the discreet values 0 and 1. Let's say you use a threshold of 0.5:

```
NNprediction_thresh_0.5 = [0 1 0 0 0 1 0];
vs. 
targetLabels             =[0 1 0 0 0 1 0];
```

With this information you can compute your False Positives, FN, TP, and TN (and a bunch of additional derived metrics such as True Positive Rate = TP/(TP+FN) ).

If you had a ROC curve showing the False Negative Rate vs. True Positive Rate, this would be a single point in the plot. However, if you vary the threshold  in the hard-limit function, you can get all the values you need for a complete curve.

Makes sense? See the dependencies of one process on the others?